# CancellationTokenSource callback is called for all request

Tags: c#, .net-5, cancellationtokensource

I set up a  CancellationTokenSource  with handler

```
public class AppTimeout
{
       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
       {
          
          var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(httpContext.RequestAborted);

          cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(myTimestamp);

      
           cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
           {    
               log.info("...");
           });
           
           await _next(httpContext);
       }
}
```

My problem is if I have only one request in timeout , the callback of cancellationTokenSource.Token is called for all request that have been processed by Invoke methode, even request that already finished in correct time

Do you know why I encounter this behaviour and how to fix it please?

Comment: Well, there's nothing to dispose of the cancellation token source, and garbage collection doesn't happen immediately, so I expect that it's timing out _after_ the request has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
using var registration = timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => {    
    log.info($"timeout path is {path}");
});
// your other code here...
```

Now it will unregister correctly when complete, i.e. when leaving the scope of the `using`.

Comment: @LemecCinq oops, see edit; if you're using an older C# compiler, you'll need to use the older `using(...) {...}` syntax

Comment: I would like to know , why use using is the solution , it is supposed to be used for releasing non managed resources , I don't see how it solve the issue even I am sur it solves it

Comment: I would be really curious to have explanation.

Comment: @vivien Because in some cases Microsoft use `IDisposable` to do things other than dispose of unmanaged resources.

Comment: @VivienPipo unmanaged resources is just *one* use of `IDisposable`. It is used in many many more places that than - including in `foreach`, for example.

Comment: yes , it can be used for scope , but I wonder in this case why it prevent the callback to be shared .In other words: Why using directly cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register make that all the request will have the same cancelationToken callback?

Comment: @VivienPipo the point is that eventually the token *was* getting cancelled, but in this case: after we cared - yet it was still performing the logging. That was because we failed to unsubscribe when we stopped caring,

Comment: than you, and why "using" allow to unsubscribe ?

Comment: @VivienPipo Because the first thing `Dispose` in [`CancellationTokenRegistration`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenRegistration.cs#L68) does is try to unregister the registration (I'm sure it's documented somewhere but I couldn't find it immediately and I'm on a mobile device).