# why CancellationTokenSource.Token.register callback is shared by all request?

Tags: c#, .net-5, cancellationtokensource

I try to understand solution of this channel [CancellationTokenSource callback is called for all request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70287889/cancellationtokensource-callback-is-called-for-all-request)
In dotnet 5

I have the code bellow

```
      public class AppTimeout
    {
    ...

    public AppTimeout(RequestDelegate next, IOptions<ServerOptions> options)
    {
...
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
            var cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(httpContext.RequestAborted);
            cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(_timeout);

            httpContext.RequestAborted = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
            var requestPath = httpContext.Request.Path;
            cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
            {
                logger.Message("... requestPath...");
            });
        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

After on request have been in timeout, The callback will be triggers for all request

But it is not case and the callback will be called only for the request in timeout just if I replace

```
cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
```

by

```
using var registration = cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() =>
```

My question is why ?
Could you explain me please?

Comment: `cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register` seems to be a popular topic _this week_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `using` statements both `cancellationTokenSource` and `registration` will continue to be active after the requests ends and eventually you will get a timeout where the callback is invoked **even though the request already ended**.  The timeout is not a timeout of the request. It's a result of a bug in the code. I'm not sure I understand why this only starts to occur after a "real" timeout but I wouldn't waste energy trying to understand that. You have to dispose `registration` and I believe also `cancellationTokenSource` when the requests ends (e.g. by using `using` statements).